# With Selenium - how can I select one element per row randomly?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, testng

I want to select one element per row in a table. The rows and columns don't have that actual value, it's just for a test.

The cssSelector for the row is **div.table_row**.

The cssSelector for the cell is **div.table_cell**.

How can I randomly select one element out of those 5 columns per row and then move to the next row and select another element randomly?

I tried doing this but of course it failed:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<WebElement> button = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(RADIO_BUTTON));
button.get(rnd.nextInt(button.size())).click();
```

Where RADIO_BUTTON is the cssSelector **div.radio_button**.
This will randomly select 10 radio buttons and the test will fail.

See table image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OBKn.png).

Trying this in selenium in Java.
I am not familiar with parent and child elements in cssSelectors.

XPath is out of discussion since the classes are randomly generated and it will fail each time.

I want it to be something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn3tR.png).

Thanks!

HTML page source:

```
   <div class="sc-eIHaNI ccrdop">
   <div id="question_container_54220043">
      <div>
         <div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: auto; min-height: 554px; max-height: 200px;">
            <div style="position: relative; overflow: scroll; margin-right: -17px; margin-bottom: -17px; min-height: 571px; max-height: 217px;">
               <div class="sc-dXLFzO oUzRG">
                  <div class="table sc-dlyikq fIjTup">
                     <div class="table_row sc-blIhvV iCLgRI">
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk iezKaA">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text"></div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk ddQJUy">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text">
                                    <div class="text" style="width: 100%;">a</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk ddQJUy">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text">
                                    <div class="text" style="width: 100%;">b</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk ddQJUy">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text">
                                    <div class="text" style="width: 100%;">c</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk ddQJUy">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text">
                                    <div class="text" style="width: 100%;">d</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk ddQJUy">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text">
                                    <div class="text" style="width: 100%;">e</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="table_row sc-blIhvV heofGg">
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk bxqvJw">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text">
                                    <div class="text" style="width: 100%;">1</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="table_row sc-blIhvV heofGg">
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk bxqvJw">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text">
                                    <div class="text" style="width: 100%;">2</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="table_row sc-blIhvV heofGg">
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk bxqvJw">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text">
                                    <div class="text" style="width: 100%;">3</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="table_row sc-blIhvV heofGg">
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk bxqvJw">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text">
                                    <div class="text" style="width: 100%;">4</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="table_row sc-blIhvV heofGg">
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk bxqvJw">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text">
                                    <div class="text" style="width: 100%;">5</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="table_row sc-blIhvV heofGg">
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk bxqvJw">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text">
                                    <div class="text" style="width: 100%;">6</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="table_row sc-blIhvV heofGg">
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-glUWqk bxqvJw">
                              <div class="sc-bTiqRo bfwdoK">
                                 <div class="table_cell_text">
                                    <div class="text" style="width: 100%;">7</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table_cell sc-bYTsla iuJcfM" width="100px">
                           <div class="sc-gQNndl ebzAHe">
                              <div class="sc-MYvYT jmUCao">
                                 <div class="radio_button sc-hwwEjo eTTyml">
                                    <div class="sc-kPVwWT eocRsE"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html page source? I think your ask is not a big deal. you will have to select each row and randomly select a radio button for each row.

Comment: Provide your relevant HTML for better solution from other contributor?

Comment: How can I provide the html page source without damaging the structure?

Comment: Inspect the element using F12 and copy the entire table and please post in text format to your original post not screenshot.

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: @javaprogrammer : I can't see any radio button in DOM you have posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide a bit of code to get you started. This code will first find all table rows, then pick a random cell per row to select. I don't actually see any `radio_button` in the HTML you provided, so I am taking a guess and assuming `<div class="table_cell_text"></div>` is the radio button element:

```
// init random
Random rnd = new Random();

// first get number of rows -- this returns 10
int rowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'table_row')]")).size();

// then iterate the rows from 2-10 (WebElement lists are 1-based index, skip first header row)
for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    // get radio buttons for this row -- use i to get the row index
    // this returns 6
    List<WebElement> cells = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'table_row')][" + i + "]//div[@class='table_cell_text']")

    // get a random cell and click it -- start with 1 so we can skip first column
    cells.get(rnd.nextInt((cells.size() - 1) + 1).click();
}
```

I started the `for` loop at 2, because we don't want to look at the first row with the column headers a,b,c,d etc. I also specified `rnd.nextInt` to pick between 1 and `cells.size()`, so that we do not pick a cell that is in the first column with data 1,2,3,4 etc.

We use the line `cells.get(rnd.nextInt((cells.size() - 1) + 1).click();` to ensure we are getting a list index that is greater than 0, but still within `cells.size()` range. `rnd.nextInt(cells.size()` returns an `int` from 0 to `cells.size()`. But, we want to skip the 0 case, so we add `+ 1` to the result. But, then we run into the `out of bounds` potential issue, so we add `- 1` to `cells.size()`.

This code is actually requesting a random int from 0 to `size() - 1`, then adding 1 to the result, so we get random int from 1 to `size()`, which enables us to skip the first column of cells that we do not want to click.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the approach like this:

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.table_row"));
// iterating over rows
for(WebElement row: tableRows){
    // Count number of cells in a row
    List<WebElement> columsInRows = row.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.table_cell"));
    Random rnd = new Random();
    // Take random item in a row
    int cellIndexToClick = rnd.nextInt(columsInRows.size());
    // Click that item
    columsInRows.get(cellIndexToClick).click();
}
```